# In Windows 8 Metro, is it possible to style the checked state of a radio button?

Tags: css, windows-8, microsoft-metro, radio-button, winjs

I've successfully styled the standard look of the radio button in Metro with

```
input[type=radio]::-ms-check { 
    border: none; 
    background: transparent url('myImage.png');
}
```

and the active state with

```
input[type=radio]::-ms-check:active { 
    border: none; 
    background: transparent url('myActiveImage.png');
}
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to style the checked state. The obvious choices don't work:

```
input[type=radio]::-ms-check:checked {}
input[type=radio]:checked {}
```

Is this even possible in Metro?

UPDATE:

```
input[type=radio]:checked::-ms-check {
    background: red;
}
```

... works to change the background color, but it does not remove the radio dot. This is what I would need to do if I want to use my own image in the background. Can the dot be removed?

Comment: I assume by "selected state" you mean "checked state". Editing your question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are not using the correct amount of colons for `::-ms-check`. It's a pseudo-element, so it has two colons. (As opposed to pseudo-selectors, which have one.)

You also have the order backward. You need to specify that you want to work with the `::-ms-check` pseudo element of a `:checked` radio button, instead of getting the `::-ms-check` pseudo-element and then trying to style a `:checked` version of it.

Thus, the following should work:

```
input[type=radio]::-ms-check {
    background: orange;
}

input[type=radio]:checked::-ms-check {
    background: blue;
    color: red; // to remove it, `color: transparent`
}
```

Live demo (for viewing in IE10): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zAwyp

Comment: Sadly, the mistake was only in transcribing the css here. I have the correct colons in my code (hence being able to change the rest and down states). Thank you for suggesting input[type=radio]:checked::-ms-check, but that does not work.

Comment: Correction. input[type=radio]:checked::-ms-check DOES affect the checked state, so I can change the background, for example, but I can't see how to remove the radio dot. Any idea on how to do that?